# Slow SQL query with many joins

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

This query is slow. Does anyone know why?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `color_idx`.`value`,
    COUNT(color_idx.entity_id) AS `count`
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN
    `searchindex_result_mage_catalog_product` AS `tmp_table`
ON
    (tmp_table.product_id=e.entity_id)  
LEFT JOIN
    `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `_inventory_table`
ON
    _inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id
INNER JOIN
    `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index`
ON
    price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
    price_index.website_id = '1' AND
    price_index.customer_group_id = 0  
INNER JOIN
    `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index`
ON
    cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND
    cat_index.store_id='1' AND
    cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND
    cat_index.category_id = '2'  
LEFT JOIN
    `sales_flat_order_item` AS `t2`
ON
    (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle')) AND
    e.entity_id = t2.product_id AND
    e.entity_type_id = 4
LEFT JOIN
    `sales_flat_order` AS `t3`
ON
    t3.entity_id = t2.order_id AND
    t3.state != 'canceled'  
INNER JOIN
    `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `color_idx`
ON
    color_idx.entity_id = e.entity_id AND
    color_idx.attribute_id = '92' AND
    color_idx.store_id = '1' 
WHERE
    (tmp_table.id IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY
    `e`.`entity_id`,
    `color_idx`.`value`
```